# Minimal spanning line for a set of points with margins

Tags: geometry, line

I have a simple programming problem related to geometry! I can solve it using pencil and paper (in visual mode!!), however I am not sure if I can program it. I don't need the code itself, but a pseudo code or an idea to implement.

The are 4 points in a line, whom position are given. Each point requires a minimum space around himself, which is given after the position of the point. We want to find the minimum (in length) line segment, which can satisfy all requirements above. In other words I need minimum spanning line over these points with minimum space around requirements.

Example:
$p_i$: (x, L), where x denotes the position (a real number), and L denotes the minimum space requirement around x.

p1: (1,1)
p2: (2,1)
p3: (5,1)
p4: (7,2)

Graphical representation:
[image: The graphical representation]

as it is shown the result is a line segment from 1 to 7 with length 6.

Another example:
p1: (2,1)
p2: (3,2)
p3: (4,1.5)
p4: (6.5,0.5)

the result (the green line below) is a line segment from 2 to 6.5 (length: 4.5)
[image: Another example]

Comment: That looks like a scheduling problem of a cpu... You want to queuee p1-p4 in a line? By the way as a simple solution add the length of all lines than you have the compleate line... not sure if that helps.

Comment: Erm... if we take as a point definition `(x, y)` pair, where `x` is position and `y` is span, can you give an example of points combination where the result line would NOT be (min x, max x)?

Comment: Yes, of course. However, I think when all points and spans are small enough !!, there is always a starting point (or finishing point), i.e. the starting or finishing point of the result is the same a one point among other ones! But if one of the spans be large, the situation is not always true. Is it true to test only start points from two directions?

Comment: So why is the result not 0..9 in your example, rather than 1..7?  What if `p4` was `(7,7)`?  If you would include the left margin of `p4`, why do you not also include the left margin of `p1`?

Comment: Please note that the minimum margin required by any point is half of the length of the line in the picture (the length is doubled in the picture to show possible starting / finishing points of margins). The line 1-7 with length 6, satisfies all requirements and is shorter than 0-9. If p4 was (7,7), the result would be (0,7). If you choose the left margin of p1, you will not give any gain and only increase the result's length. There is no rule about left or right margins that can be generalized to all points. I think my question must be more clear now, however I am here to get my answer.

Comment: *There is no rule about left or right margins that can be generalized to all points.* - In that case you need to include it in the input, e.g. separate left/right margins per point, because otherwise the algorithm has no way to know if (for example) you want the left and right margins of `p2` but only the right margin of `p1`.

Comment: As I said there is no general rule..., I mean it is not required for all points to select the same margin for themselves and the algorithm must select the correct side for each point during run time. I will upload more examples in the original question.

Comment: You can ask me about the result of a set of 4 points and I will answer you, however I can not express the process in my mind algorithmically. I hope you can answer me.

Answer (score 0):

The length of optimal result is always more than max(x_i)-min(x_i)  i=1,2,3,4

It is also easy that always there is an optimal solution where one end point of it is matched to an x_i, i.e. you can roll the spanning optimal result to be matched with a point, for example x_1.

Sweep from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Start x_1 and span it over its right margin. additionally start all other points you can (i.e. points that their left margin have been started). In other words start the first point as late as possible, after it, start all other points as soon as possible.
Finally, if there is a point x_i, where its left margin has been started before x_1, call this diference as diff_i. Add all diff_i to all x_i s and find all segments out of the final point of the results (i.e if (x_i+diff_i>current_end_position then current_end_position=x_i+diff_i.

Thanks for your comments.